# Android - Multilevel Listview using Fragment

Tags: android, android-listview

So, I have a listview of **parent category A**.

Now if I press one of the item in the list, it will go to its corresponding **child category B**.

Should I use fragment in **category B**? Before this I fired an intent to a new activity to show a list of **category B**. Right now I am using fragment in **category A**, so I am asking, is it a best practice to make the child listview a fragment too?

If so, is there any tutorial on how to do multilevel listview using fragments? Or should I reuse the fragment in Listview A to populate listview B?

Here is how I do it:

In `mainactivity` contains navigation drawer item:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          // add navdraweritems
          // set adapter for navdraweritems
        }

        // do the rest of the activity
        // navdraweritems listener
}
```

In `CategoryFragment`:

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container,
                false);

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.catListView);
        listView.setAdapter(va);

        loadCategory();

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Where should I put the itemclicklistener for the next page (child listview B)?

Answer (score 1):

this is very useful example .

[reference link](http://www.easyinfogeek.com/2013/07/full-example-of-using-fragment-in.html)

in this example,it is use listview in fragement class..
i hope its useful to you

Answer (score 1):

> reuse the fragment in Listview A to populate listview B

But when you do that make sure you handle the Back Button properly.If `Category B` is another `ListView` call

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

References:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: If I use ListFragment instead of Fragment, does that mean I have to use setListAdapter instead of a custom adapter? Because in the doc says, "Do not directly call ListView.setAdapter() or else important initialization will be skipped." What does that mean?

Comment: If you plan on using a `ListView` in your `Fragment` then use `ListFragment` `setListAdapter`. It's an adapter implementation for `ListFragment`.